# Bi Publisher Excel preview won't preview the right version

Tags: excel, bi-publisher

**H**i everyone,

**D**uring my development on BI Publisher for Excel I ran into a problem,

**I** made a first version of the template without any problems, i could preview the result just right.
But since a while, when i use the preview button : I only get the old preview version, not the preview of the actual file I just modified.

**W**here things get odd is that even with an all new, blank xls template I get to preview the template I did few days ago(one thing tho, its only the template, if i take different data, i get the output that goes with the data).

**W**hen I send by mail my template and the xml data to a co-worker, he can preview it just right.

**T**hanks for your help !

---

#### More informations :

*Softwares :*

- Office 2013(x64)
- Last version of BI Publisher add-in for office(x64)
- Windows 7x64(VM)

Comment: I already tried some solutions like :
clearing temporary files.
uninstalling/re-installing Bi Publisher Desktop
uninstalling/re-installing Office

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem :
 BiPublisher for desktop was stuck into using an old template into a tmp folder.

- The solution i found so far is to get to 
  "C:\Users*Username*\AppData\Local\Oracle\BIPublisher\TemplateBuilderforExcel\tmp\tmp"
  and then delete "tmp.xls"

I don't know for how long it will fix the issue, but at least it can fix it one preview at a time.

Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting `tmp.xls` to fix this issue.